# What is "desysopped"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Rollback_feature:

> Standard rollback may only be used in certain situations – editors who
>   misuse standard rollback (for example, by using it to reverse
>   good-faith edits in situations where an explanatory edit summary would
>   normally be expected) may have their rollback rights removed. Since
>   rollback is part of the core administrator tools, an admin could
>   theoretically be desysopped in order to remove those tools.

I couldn't understand the last sentence, I was wondering what's "desysopped" ?

Comment: First time I've found a word Google can't understand.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It means "to have administrator privileges removed from their account".

Another name for an administrator is a "sysop" (short for System Operator), so it's a case of verbing. It would probably be clearer if they hyphenated it: de-sysopped.